# Column not defined in current context

Tags: dax

I'm trying something very simple in DAX:

```
[Balance] := 'Inventory'[Inventory Amount]*10
```

I get a "column does not exist in current context" error. What does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because it was expecting an aggregate. You are creating a calculated measure but referring to a row and it doesn't have context for this row. I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. If you need to calculate things on a row level, you'll need to use a SUMX (or you need to create a calculated column that multiplies the Inventory Amount column by 10 and then SUM it. Otherwise, you can use SUM with just one calc.

If you just need to add all the inventory amounts on every row in the query context and then multiply by 10, you can do

```
Balance:= SUM('Inventory'[Inventory Amount])
```

If the number you multiple will not always be 10, I suggest putting that formula in a separate calculated *column* (let's call it 'Inventory[Factor]. Then create a calculation like:

```
Balance:= SUMX('Inventory', 'Inventory'[Inventory Amount] * 'Inventory'[Factor])
```

The difference between these two is that the SUM will do the aggregation first. The SUMX will do the row-level calculation first and then aggregate. Since I don't know what you are trying to do, I gave you both options. SUMX will probably be slower, so you probably want to avoid that.

[Here](http://www.powerpivotpro.com/2014/10/sum-sumx-or-calculatechoices-choices/) is a relevant blog post on the subject. In general check out PowerPivotPro.com and DaxPatterns.com when trying to find your way through DAX.